# Javafx button does nothing

Tags: java, eclipse, scenebuilder

I'm creating a simple login GUI form using eclipse, JavaFX and scene builder. I've coded my program so that every time I click the login button, it would switch to another window but it doesn't work. i'm a beginner in java but we've been tasked to create a system in my class so I've only relied on youtube tutorials, any help would be appreciated!

this is my main code

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

my login form

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Login {

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField password;

    @FXML
    private TextField username;

    @FXML
    private Label wrongLogin;

    @FXML
    public void Login(ActionEvent event) {
        
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        
        if (username.getText().equals("admin") && password.getText().equals("admin")) {
            try {
                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("BookRooms.fxml"));
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

my fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="345.0" prefWidth="545.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff2cc;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Login">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="132.0" layoutY="62.0" prefHeight="221.0" prefWidth="279.0" style="-fx-background-color: #545454; -fx-border-radius: 10;">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="34.0" layoutY="60.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="56.0" text="Username:" textFill="WHITE" />
            <Label layoutX="34.0" layoutY="98.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="56.0" text="Password:" textFill="WHITE" />
            <TextField layoutX="106.0" layoutY="60.0" promptText="Enter Username ID:" />
            <TextField layoutX="106.0" layoutY="98.0" promptText="Enter Password" />
            <Button alignment="CENTER" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="137.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="73.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff2cc;" text="LOGIN" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
      <Label layoutX="225.0" layoutY="36.0" text="HOTEL DEL LUNA" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button in fxml can't call Login() in its controller class because there is no onAction attribute in fxml button tag .
So ,in `<Button alignment="CENTER" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="137.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="73.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff2cc;" text="LOGIN" />` add  `onAction="#Login"` inside Button Tag:

```
<Button alignment="CENTER" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="137.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Login" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="73.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff2cc;" text="LOGIN" />
```

And , naming a method in a class with exact the same name of that class is concidered a bad practice. Only constructors must match its name with class identifier

Comment: thank you for your help! i've done what you suggested and when i clicked the login button, the console displayed a bunch of errors
```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
 at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
```

I also tried to change the action name and vice versa, and when I tried to run my program it won't even display the login form anymore

Comment: there are many errors  in your code . 1 there is no PaswordField   in  your fxml  file 2  your textfield userename tag does not have  an id attribute in your case  fx:id="username" . 3 your Textfield in fxml file does not have an id again in your case  fx:id="passWord"   and your Login class has a PassworField change it for TextField